# How do I make a transparent mask div on top of an iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, opacity, mask

I have an iframe of my Blogger page on my website, with the intention of looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lndg6.jpg). To avoid having the text get cut off at the bottom of the iframe window, which would look awkward, I wanted to have a gradient transparency mask at the bottom of the iframe window to smooth it out.

I've tried the transparency effect on the iframe itself, but it applied to the bottom of the iframe page, so I figured that an overlaying div should do it.

I know how to make the div and position it, but I have no idea how to apply that effect.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide us with some sample code to work with.

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work for you?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden
}

iframe {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.iframe-cover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent, black, black);
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.bing.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<!--Bing is just a place holder-->
<div class="iframe-cover"></div>
```